# Can't execute `pecl upgrade-all` - stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto

Tags: linux, php, proxy, opensuse, pecl

I tried to execute `pecl upgrade-all` but I get:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_host in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_port in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Could not establish SSL connection through proxy ::

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_host in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_port in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Could not establish SSL connection through proxy ::

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_host in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_port in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Could not establish SSL connection through proxy ::

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_host in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_port in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Could not establish SSL connection through proxy ::

Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 105

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_host in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_host in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107

Notice: Undefined variable: proxy_port in PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: proxy_port in /usr/local/lib64/php/PEAR/Proxy.php on line 107
Error getting channel info from pear.php.net: Could not establish SSL connection through proxy ::
Nothing to upgrade-all
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using a proxy server to access the Internet?

Comment: Yes, I am behind a proxy. Didn't knew it either, my colleague setup the server. So it does not work with proxy? Or do I have to configure pecl to use the proxy?
EDIT: Found the command to proxy information to pecl here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266500/4684797

Unfortunatelly I don't know the password. Will have to ask my colleague.

Comment: Im not authorized to get the password. So I can't use pecl. Thx